# Trouble with calling PS script (with parameter) from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to setup a simple .aspx web page that will accept a user's input of a  string (later, more than one string) and use that string as the parameter value for a Powershell script.

The PS script looks like this right now:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string] $ServiceName
)

$ServiceName | out-file c:\it\test.txt 
$ServiceName | Out-String
```

The C# code looks like this:

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();

// Add the script to the PowerShell object
shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\it\\test.ps1 -ServiceName BITS");

// Execute the script
var results = shell.Invoke();
```

When I run that, I get "BITS" written to the test.txt file. What I need to do now, is setup the application to call the script, passing in the "ServiceName" parameter. I found this: [Call PowerShell script file with parameters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552404/call-powershell-script-file-with-parameters-in-c-sharp) and tried the following code:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"c:\it\test.ps1").AddParameter("ServiceName", "BITS");
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

In this case, the script was called and the test.txt file was created, but the value (BITS) was not written to the file. What am I missing here? Why isn't the parameter being passed to the script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
var ps = @"C:\it\test.ps1";
processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "-File " + ps + " -ServiceName BITS);
```

I don't like this as much, but it works. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Here are three possible solutions for future readers including me:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
   //Solution #1
   //ps.AddCommand(@"C:\it\test.ps1", true).AddParameter("ServiceName", "BITS");
   //Solution #2
   //ps.AddScript(@"C:\it\test.ps1 -ServiceName 'BITS'", true);
   //Solution #3
   ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\it\test.ps1"), true).AddParameter("ServiceName", "BITS");

   Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
}
```

I haven't seen solution #3 documented anywhere else, though I got the idea for it from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/