# Calling powershell script from WPF application doesn't execute script

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

I try to call a powershell script from within an WPF application (in *App.xaml.cs*) like this:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\WIN-SRV-2019\Betreuung-Release\Install.ps1";

  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit();
  // ...
}
```

As a result the powershell window opens up shortly and then closes immediately without executing the script.

When i perform the following command on the command line (CMD):

```
C:\Users\Entwicklung>powershell \\WIN-SRV-2019\Betreuung-Release\Install.ps1
```

... everything works fine. The script gets executed as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because in your test you are running cmd but in the code you want to run powershell? theres the problem

Comment: you can call PowerShell like this, your answer found here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552404/call-powershell-script-file-with-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks but it should be possible to call powershell using Process, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/de-DE/bfb27da8-65c6-40b7-9a3e-a4718850d849/launch-a-powershell-script-from-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: It is possible, but it's not the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. I had to add `-executionpolicy unrestricted` to the arguments:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-executionpolicy unrestricted \\WIN-SRV-2019\Betreuung-Release\Install.ps1";

  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit();
  // ...
}
```